# Subclass existing window with Win32

Tags: c++, winapi

I am currently trying to grab all of the user input to the windows calculator app. It seems the way to do this is to use Win32 to intercept all of the keyboard and mouse inputs that are intended for the calculator window. I have read the MSDN page on subclassing a window at the link below and have done some research on subclassing.

I have the syntax for subclassing a window, but I am not sure how to tell the program which window I am looking to subclass.

the code that I have so far is listed below. My problem right now is that I am not sure how the variable "hWndEdit" is assigned. I am pretty new to Win32 programming so any help is appreciated.

(link)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633570(v=vs.85).aspx

```
WNDPROC wpOrigEditProc; 

wpOrigEditProc = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLong(hWndEdit,GWL_WNDPROC,(long) WndEditProc);

LRESULT CALLBACK WndEditProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message) 
        {
        case WM_CHAR:
        case WM_KEYUP:
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            if (hWnd == hWndEdit)
                return 0;
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY: 
            // Remove the subclass from the edit control. 
            SetWindowLong(hWndEdit, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG) wpOrigEditProc); 
        break;
        default:
            return CallWindowProc((WNDPROC ) wpOrigEditProc, hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    return CallWindowProc((WNDPROC ) wpOrigEditProc, hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Let's step back a little bit. What is the problem you're trying to solve where intercepting input to Calc is the solution?

Comment: Your about to take a long run with this. You're not only asking to subclass a window procedure, you're asking to do it in a process that isn't even yours. There are ways to do it, but if you're just starting out in Win32 programming you may way to get your feet wet or at least read up quite a bit more. secondary process subclassing via hooks and/or injections is not for the feint of heart.

Comment: Subclassing a window in your own process is a pretty standard winapi technique.  Subclassing a window in another process most certainly is not, it requires injecting a DLL into the process.  If you can't even *find* the window you want to subclass then you just got a little lost in what's practical and what is not.  Altering the behavior of another program that you don't have the source code for is just not a common practice.  Mostly because a simple update to such a program, outside of your control, will break your code.

Comment: Not to mention the security concerns. (which I just did, darn it).

Comment: The end goal of this is to restrict the user from interacting with the calculator program when my program is running. I am using python 2.3 (I am stuck at this version) and have access to the pywin32 module. I first was trying to complete this task in CPP and then convert it over but from what you guys are saying makes it seem more difficult than I had first imagined. Is there a better way to prevent the user from interacting with the calculator window?

Comment: You could just disable the Calculator window. But it's still an odd question. Why shouldn't the user be able to use the Calculator program? (Is this to prevent cheating on a math test? There are other calculators in the system beyond the built-in Calculator program.)

Comment: If I understand correctly if I was to disable the calculator window that would prevent it from showing up at all. I need the window to be open and essentially read only. Only my program would interact with the calculator, the user wouldn't be able to do anything to it themselves without going through my program. This may not have much application for the calculator program itself but it is an example of what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Maybe you should just delete the built-in calculator app (or restrict launching it) and write your own full-blown calculator.  It would be less work and then you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: That would work for a solution to the example but it doesn't solve the problem unfortunately because of my situation. For example if someone wants to add 2+2, instead of typing it into the calculator app window, they would call a function within my program to implement the 2+2 calculation. The calculator would then show: 2+2=4. By doing it this way I will be able to use the functionality of the calculator program (or any more complex program) and record all of the information being sent to and from the calculator program in my program.

Answer (score 0):

To find a window, first use Spy++ (A tool that gets installed with Visual Studio) to find the class name and the window name of the calculator main window. Then, in your application, use the [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499.aspx) API:

```
hWndEdit = FindWindow(className, windowName);
```

Although, I'm not sure that subclassing is the right method here since the Calculator window is not owned by your application. You should do this with [hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589.aspx).

Comment: Note that calc has lots of buttons and other controls. Those will be separate windows. Depending on what this subclassing is supposed to do, it might be necesary to subclass them all.

Comment: I will look into hooks, Thanks for the recommendation. I'll let you know how it goes.